# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Internal Error)

Tags: payment-gateway, payumoney

the errors in payumoney integration i stuck before 3 days.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi99T.png) 
checkout.citruspay.com/payu/icpcheckout/:1 Failed to load ,

GET https://checkout.citruspay.com/payu/icpcheckout/%3Cimage%20path%3E 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Any solution for this?